# How do I change the footer position in Drupal?

Tags: php, html, css, drupal

Ok so my site is http://www.raptorshop.com - based in Drupal 6.x - and I've got a footer, however it appears that the footer is at the bottom of the page content - I want the footer to be at the bottom of the entire document/browser window.

How would I go about doing this?

I can't seem to find a setting or way to do this.

Comment: you are looking for a css sticky footer solution

Comment: I don't know quite what this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try a different theme - see the themes listed at http://drupal.org/project/themes. (Make sure you download one which is compatible with Drupal 6.)

Different themes put their footers in different places. You can also replace the standard footer with a block, and put that in any of the block regions.

If you can't find a theme which looks exactly how you want it to, you can try creating your own - this is more difficult unless you're very happy with HTML/CSS/PHP etc. This is a good place to start: http://drupal.org/node/805968.